# Write EXIF data to image stream Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, stdout, exif

I found a nice npm package that allows you to read and write Exif data to images, https://github.com/Sobesednik/node-exiftool.

The challenge that I have is that it requires you to provide the path to an image. So, the image has to be written to disk if you want to modify the EXIF using this package. Is there an easy way to check/read the EXIF, and if necessary, write EXIF data to an image stream?

```
var imageURL = 'https://nodejs.org/static/images/logos/nodejs-new-pantone-black.png'
var upstreamServer = 'http://someupstreamserver/uploads'

request
  .get(imageURL)
  .pipe(
      // TODO read EXIF
      // TODO write missing EXIF
      request
        .post(upstreamServer, function(err, httpResponse, body){
          res.send(201)
      })
  )
```

EDIT: This question was also asked on node-exiftool

Comment: I assume you've asked this on "Sobesednik"'s repo, too. If not: why are you not asking the one person we at least know is the expert? best case, your question leads to the library being extended to work with streams, and everyone wins. Not just you. Because open source is for everyone.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Yes, I only posted this an hour ago and will be posting to his repo. Not sure of the need for your comment, though. Stack Overflow is open to the world. Maybe someone will direct me and the others reading this to a better repo or better way of doing this.

Comment: Mostly because of the "search and research before posting" policy - if you ask on SO, what better than to have a question that goes "I asked this over on the node-exiftool repository too, at (and then a link here)", because now we have a *really* good question when people find it next week, next month, maybe even next year. Instead of being a dead end, it'll link straight to the most important place you can link through to.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I researched this before posting. And I linked to the repo in my original post, but agree that I can add to my SO question that the question was also asked over on node-exiftool. My intention is not for this to be a dead end. If I only asked the question over at node-exiftool then it would be limited to that repo and the author responding. Maybe there is a better way of doing what I am trying to do? Which is why I posted the question. When I find the answer, I will post it here.

Comment: A classic reading mistake: I never asked you to do something *instead* of posting here. As you rightly point out, that would be limiting. I asked you whether you asked this on the repo, because having that information in the question (which kind of implies doing both things) makes this question *far* better. Can you change that edit to not say "edit:...." but just say "I asked this over on (and then the link to the issue here) as well, and will update this post with an answer if a solution is found there" or something?

Answer (score 1):

i had a similar task. I had to write physical dimensions and additional metadata to PNG files. I have found some solutions and combined it into one small library.
 [png-metadata](https://github.com/hometlt/png-metadata/tree/master)

it could read PNG metadata from NodeJS Buffers, and create a new Buffers with new metadata.

Here is an example:

```
        const buffer = fs.readFileSync('1000ppcm.png')
        console.log(readMetadata(buffer));

        withMetadata(buffer,{
            clear: true, //remove old metadata
            pHYs: { //300 dpi
                x: 30000,
                y: 30000,
                units: RESOLUTION_UNITS.INCHES
            },
            tEXt: {
                Title:            "Short (one line) title or caption for image",
                Author:           "Name of image's creator",
                Description:      "Description of image (possibly long)",
                Copyright:        "Copyright notice",
                Software:         "Software used to create the image",
                Disclaimer:       "Legal disclaimer",
                Warning:          "Warning of nature of content",
                Source:           "Device used to create the image",
                Comment:          "Miscellaneous comment"
            }
        });
```

It  could be modified to be used with streams, for example, you could implement WritableBufferStream  class.

```
const { Writable } = require('stream');

/**
 * Simple writable buffer stream
 * @docs: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_streams
 */
class WritableBufferStream extends Writable {

  constructor(options) {
    super(options);
    this._chunks = [];
  }

  _write(chunk, enc, callback) {
    this._chunks.push(chunk);
    return callback(null);
  }

  _destroy(err, callback) {
    this._chunks = null;
    return callback(null);
  }

  toBuffer() {
    return Buffer.concat(this._chunks);
  }
}
```